# CreateBuffer throwing an "Access violation reading location"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx-11

I have a function, inside a class called ModelClass, that does the following:

```
bool ModelClass::SetVertices(ID3D11Device* device, VertexType* vertices)
{
    // Error catching variable
    HRESULT result;

    // Setup the vertex buffer description
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc));
    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertices)*24; 
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    //vertexBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = 0;

    // Give the subresource structure a pointer to the vertex data.
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexData;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexData, sizeof(vertexData));
    vertexData.pSysMem = vertices;
    vertexData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    vertexData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    // Create the Vertex Buffer
    result = device->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexData, &m_vertexBuffer);

    if (FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Running this, gives me an error message saying "Unhandled exception at 0x00E445A2 in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.", with visual studio pointing at the `result = ...` line. I can not, for the life of me, figure out why it's doing this. I don't even know what else to post, so I'll just enumerate things I find relevant:

```
ModelClass::ModelClass(ID3D11Device* device, VertexType* vertices, unsigned long* indices)
{
    m_vertexBuffer = 0;
    m_indexBuffer = 0;

    SetVertices(device, vertices);
    SetIndices(device, indices);
}
```

- The class is being defined with `ModelClass* cube1 = new ModelClass(d3d11Device, v, indices);`, in the global scope (for now) with the constructor in the code box above.
- The `m_vertexBuffer` variable is declared as `ID3D11Buffer *m_vertexBuffer` in the class header file, and initialized to zero in the class constructor.
- DirectX 11 on Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8.1 64bit
- If I copy the contents of the SetVertices function into my main file (which holds most of the setting up), it immediately works without this error. It only happens if I call CreateBuffer from inside the class. This works the exactly the same way for my index buffer, which indicates it's not a problem with the vertex structure
- All functions and variables of the class are public
- CreateBuffer still throws that exception even if one, more or all of it's arguments are set to NULL (i.e. I don't think it's a problem with m_vertexBuffer, the data, or buffer description)
- My main guess is that it has something to do with how classes use these functions, but I can't find anything wrong with my code

Please, if you would like to see the rest of the files, just comment and I will pastebin the entire thing if it's necessary, this is driving me up the wall already

Comment: I assume you have checked the obvious, that the `device` pointer being passed in is not `NULL`?

Comment: I swear I have checked every single one of these variables except for the device. It IS null! I imagine it's because since it's on global scope, it gets defined before the device is even created, so it only passes the null declaration of the device, that I also set as a global variable. Am I right?

Comment: @daniel Haha, you beat my answer by 9 seconds.  Glad you could figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fantastic site, [RasterTek](http://rastertek.com).

Anyways, the problem is that you're initializing this thing in the global scope - before `d3d11Device` is initialized.  Everything declared in the global scope is created instantly when the program starts in an arbitrary order.  On the other hand, `d3d11Device` is not initialized when the program starts.

Take it out of the global scope or re-add the `Initialize` function from the tutorial.  Problem solved.

Comment: I'm mixing up a bunch of tutorials as I learn (and fail) at this thing, but yea, as dvnrrs commented above, that is exactly the problem. Thanks so much, I've been fighting this thing for the past 6 hours!

Comment: @daniel [I know that feel, bro.](http://static2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20130924050516/warframe/images/5/5f/I_know_that_feel_bro.jpg)